# Doubt regarding SHM in a U-Tube using energy conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator

While finding the SHM equation for liquid in a U tube using energy conservation, we have:$$E=K+U \tag{1}$$
$$K=\frac12Mv^2$$
where $v=\dot{y}$

[image]

For claculation of  $U$, it is given in "Vibrations and waves" by AP French, that:

> The **increase in gravitational potential energy** in the situation corresponds to taking a coloumn of liquid of length $y$ from left-hand tube, raising it through the distance $y$, and placing it on the top of the right-hand column. Thus we can put:$$U=g\rho Ay^2\tag{2}$$

I think that in eq(1), we should have used the value of potential energy $U$, not $\Delta{U}$, the increase in potential energy, as given in the book. So the Eq(2) according to me should be :$$ U= U( of\space Water\space above\space equilibrium) + U(of\space water\space below\space equilibrium)$$ which can be calculated by arbitrarily defining point of $U=0$ as the equilibrium point:
$$U=\int_0^{y}dmgy + \int_0^{-y}dmgy + U(of\space arc)$$

Why is the method given in the book justified? There are no increase/decrease terms in eq 1. Conservation of Mechanical energy deals with energies at a particular instant. Sum of $U$ and  $K$at an instant is constant. Increases/decreases in $U$ are not referenced. But the author talks about increase in $U$ and substitutes the increase in eq(1). I don't think it is right.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the difference between the book and what you are saying.

Comment: The book mentions increase in PE. But there is no $\Delta{U}$ in Eq 1.  Eq 1 only talks about absolute $U$ not changes in $U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy $U$ is a function of the displacement $y$ from the liquid's equilibrium position. Although the final answer will be symmetric in $y$, for the sake of definiteness let's take $y$ to be positive when the liquid in the right hand side of the tube is raised by a distance $y$. If the absolute potential energy at the equilibrium position is $U_E$ (relative to some zero point, which we shall see is arbitrary) then we have

$$U(y) = U_E + g \rho A y^2$$

We also know that the kinetic energy $K$ is a function of the liquid's velocity $v$:

$$K(v) = \frac 1 2 M v^2$$

Finally, we know that the total energy $E=U(y)+K(v)$ is constant. So

$\displaystyle \frac {dE}{dt} = 0
\\ \displaystyle  \Rightarrow \frac{dU}{dt} + \frac{dK}{dt}=0
\\ \displaystyle  \Rightarrow \frac{dU}{dy} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{dK}{dv} \frac{dv}{dt}=0$

Since we are not interested in $U$ itself, but only in its derivative $\frac {dU}{dy}$, we can see that the value of $U_E$ is irrelevant since this constant term will disappear when we differentiate $U$. The book is implicitly setting $U_E$ to $0$ without explaining why this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If the bottom section were horizontal and the datum for potential energy were taken as the bottom, then the total potential energy would be $$U=\rho gA \frac{(H+y)^2}{2}+\rho gA \frac{(H-y)^2}{2}=\rho gA(2H^2+y^2)$$where H is the equilibrium height; and the total kinetic energy would be $$K=\frac{M}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$$So the total mechanical energy would be:
$$E=\rho gA(2H^2+y^2)+\frac{M}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$$The rate of change of kinetic energy would then be $$d\frac{dE}{dt}=2\rho gAy\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)+M\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0 $$The equation would then reduce to $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{2\rho gA}{M}y=0$$
This result would not change if the bottom were curved.